# For what value of k does the following system have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra

So I guess this question states that we know we have a unique solution we just want to know what value of "k"  will allow this. Would I even have to take the determinant since I already know there is a unique solution? Or is the answer I get from the determinant the value of k?

> For what value of $k$ does the  following system of equations
>   \begin{align*}x-3y&=6\\x+3z&=-3\\2x+ky+(3-k)z&=1\end{align*}
>   have a unique solution?

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{ccc|c}
      1&-3&0&6\\
      1&0&3&-3\\
      2&k&3-k&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

Also when I take the determinant of this matrix can I ignore the numbers to the right of the horizontal line.

det = 1|3k| + 3|(3-k)-6|+(0)|k|

Comment: I think there is a sign error in the 1st term of your determinant. As long as your determinant is nonzero, there should be a unique solution.

Comment: oh right it would be -3k for the first determinant and then the value of k=-3/2, so there is a unique solution

Answer (score 4):

You can also do row reduction:

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-3&0&6\\0&1&1&-3\\0&k+6&3-k&-11\\\end{bmatrix}$

In order to have a unique solution, the third row cannot be [0 0 0], therefore $k+6\not=0, 3-k\not=0$

$k\not=-6$ and $k\not=3$

Comment: I think your last row is incorrect and also your reasoning. $k$ would need to be simultaneously those values which is impossible.

Comment: Ok. I See. Your matrix is OK but your reasoning is still incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track.

For the system to have
a unique solution,
the determinant has to be non-zero.

Simplify your expression
and see what you get.

If the determinant *is* zero,
then there are either
no solutions
or an infinite number of solutions
depending on the
right side.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is given that you have to find suitable k for the problem to have unique solution asserts that problem has already unique solution. i.e. rank of matrix = rank of augmented matrix = no. of unknowns=3.
i.e.
rank of matrix should be 3.means determinant should be non zero.rank of augmented matrix should be 3 as well and rank of augmented matrix is always greater than or equal to rank of matrix.rank of augmented matrix can't be 4.
so,eliminate all values of k which gives matrix of determinant zero.rest all are answer to your problem.

Comment: Thats what I was wondering, would I just row reduce and find what  k values  can't exist;  like what @Miles suggested above?